# what will be 0th index for array in this case?

Tags: java, arrays

```
for (int i=1;i<=5;i++)
System.out.println (“X = “ + x[i]);
```

I have read that array index starts with 0. Here we start with index i=1. So in this case, what will be value at x[0] ?

I am a beginner in coding world, please forgive if its silly question.I would have tried myself out but my compiler is yet to be installed.

Comment: You have shown where the array is printed, not where its values are set.

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: It must be Java. I'll add the tag.

Comment: You should start by installing a compiler. There is no way you're going to be able to learn to write code if you can't even compile it.

Comment: Whether array index start from 0 rely on what language you use. For c,c++ it is true. But for other languages, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have initialized the array,x[0] still is the same x[0] with the same array.

if not x[0] will be garbage data(c/c++)
and in Java, here it is [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5), different kind of array have different default value

the for loop is a count way.It doesn't affect the result.Just like you start with a book at page 2,but it doesn't affect the content at page 1

```
I would have tried myself out but my compiler is yet to be installed.
```

if you are using Linux,you can use your Linux package management tool to install the Java compiler like apt in Ubuntu.You just need to type

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

if you are using OS X or Windows, go to the [Oracle JDK download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html),download and install it like a normal software.

Then you can use the java compiler.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining in an interesting way & other information. The link is very good.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the array creation, but in general, with Java, the variable (or array element) is set to the "all zeros" value for the type. So for `int`, that's `0`; for an object reference type, that's `null`.

So unless you set a different value for it, `x[0]` will be the "all zeros" value for the element type of the array.

Note that given your loop, your array must have **six** places in it, or you'll get an error. Index `5` (the maximum value of `i` in your loop) is the *sixth* element in the array:

```
x[0] one
x[1] two
x[2] three
x[3] four
x[4] five
x[5] six
```

In most modern programming languages (including Java), your loop should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
    System.out.println("X = " + x[i]);
}
```

...where we assume the array has five places. Note that I didn't hardcode the top limit; I asked the array what it should be.

> I would have tried myself out but my compiler is yet to be installed.

Installing the compiler and learning the basics of how to use it should be your first step. But until you have it installed, you can use services that let you compile and run code on their server, from your browser. Here are two where you can use Java: [ideone](http://ideone.com/), [CompileOnline](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php).

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping & valuable information about ideone & CompileOnline ! The loop just wants to print numbers with by using the   loop variable.The confusion is clear now.